# Uploading to subversion using git

Tags: git, git-svn

How do I upload a local git repository to an empty (new) subversion remote repository?

I don't need to preserve my commit history, I just need the files to be uploaded to the remote server.

I've tried setting up a remote repository and committing with git svn:

```
git svn init https://path.to.subversion/project/trunk

git svn dcommit
```

However I get the error:

```
"Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history."
```

Please can someone advise?

Comment: In the end I just used svn directly to do this: 
--- svn mkdir https://path.to.subversion/project
--- svn import local-project https://path.to.subversion/project

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone the remote SVN repo with `git svn init https://path.to.subversion/project -T trunk -b branches -t tags`
2. Copy your files over / do whatever you want / work as with ordinary Git repo (commit, etc.)
3. Once everything is committed, push to SVN with `git svn dcommit`